# 'The document has no page' error thrown when closing a document

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm generating, saving and writing PDF on output stream.

I'm getting a `The document has no page` error while writing on output stream.

What is the problem?

```
string contents;
string fileName = "aaa.pdf";
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
hw.AddStyleAttribute("font-size","11px");
abs.RenderControl(hw);
string path = Server.MapPath("../Images/a.png");
contents = sw.ToString();
contents = contents.Replace("../Images/a.png", path);
sw.Close();
hw.Close();       
StringReader sr = new StringReader(contents);

System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/pdf/") + fileName, FileMode.Create);
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30,5,35,5);
Document cpdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 5, 35, 5);

pdfDoc.PageCount = 2;
cpdfDoc.PageCount = 2;
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc,fs);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
fs.Close();
HTMLWorker htmlparser2 = new HTMLWorker(cpdfDoc);               
PdfWriter.GetInstance(cpdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
cpdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser2.Parse(sr);

cpdfDoc.Close();    

Response.Write(cpdfDoc);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

No problem in saving. I'm getting error on this line `cpdfDoc.Close();`.

Comment: You get a "Document has no pages" exception when no content was added to the Document instance. There was probably nothing that could be parsed in your HTML.

Comment: But the stored pdf contains data..

Comment: But the content stream is empty.

Answer (score 1):

use this code and set your pdf location. and image path.
its working.

```
string contents = "hi";
        string fileName = "aaa.pdf";
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        hw.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "11px");

        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/a.png");

        contents = contents.Replace("~/Images/a.png", path);
        sw.Close();
        hw.Close();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(contents);

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/") + DateTime.Now.Ticks, FileMode.Create);
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 5, 35, 5);
        Document cpdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 5, 35, 5);

        pdfDoc.PageCount = 2;
        cpdfDoc.PageCount = 2;
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        fs.Close();
        HTMLWorker htmlparser2 = new HTMLWorker(cpdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(cpdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        cpdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser2.Parse(sr);
```

don't use this line

```
contents = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: You have removed the purpose of HtmlTextWriter. I'm getting content from html control

Comment: what is 'abs'? first tell me than i giving solution.

Comment: 'abs' is a id of div which contains data for pdf.

Comment: one thing is why are you parse StringReader sr 2 times in HTMLWorker.
'htmlparser.Parse(sr);'
' htmlparser2.Parse(sr);'

Comment: i'm storing pdf in some location[htmlparser.Parse(sr)] and writing on output stream[htmlparser2.Parse(sr)].

Comment: why are you do like this? what is your reqmnt?

Comment: i'm generating pdf on button click. pdf must be stored in some place(for reuse) and i'm writing the same pdf on output stream to view(same button click)..

Comment: means are you create 2 pdf Document. b'coz as per see your code you are create pdfDoc and cpdfDoc Document. output pdf is 1 ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33119/discussion-between-balaji-and-manish-sharma)